# django add filters in template is not working expectedly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-filter

I am a Django and Python beginner, and I encountered a problem while using Django. I hope to use a filter in the template to get the string I need, but the result below is not what I expected.

```py
# filter definition

@register.filter
def to_class_name(obj):
    return obj.__class__.__name__
```

```
# HTML template for UpdateView (This template will be used by multiple models.)
# object = Order()

{{ object|to_class_name }} #reulst: Order

{{ 'wms'|add:object|to_class_name }} #result: str, expect: object
```

I roughly understand that the issue lies with the order, but it seems I can't add parentheses to modify it.

```
{{ 'wms'|add:(object|to_class_name) }} #cause SyntaxError
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or is there a better way to determine the page data I need to output based on the model class when multiple models share one template? Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I roughly understand that the issue lies with the order, but it seems I can't add parentheses to modify it.

You can use variables. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

One way is to use `with` tag.

> it caches a complex variable under a simpler name.
> The variable is available until the `{% endwith %}` tag appears.

eg.

```
{% with firstname="Tobias" %}
<h1>Hello {{ firstname }}, how are you?</h1>
{% endwith %}
```

In your case, something like this

```
{% with class_name=object|to_class_name %}
   {{ 'wms'|add:class_name }}
{% endwith %}
```

Another approach is to use `firstof` tag. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof)

```
{% firstof object|to_class_name as class_name %}
{{ 'wms'|add:class_name }}
```